# Amazon Cognito - AdminCreateUser - how to not skip email verification

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito user pool and [`AdminCreateUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html) api to create a new user so that we don't allow users to sign themselves up. It works great but it seems that email verification step is being skipped so when making an api call, I needed to set `email_verified` attribute to true to make `reset password` flow to work.

Can I make `email verification` to happen before sending out an inviatation email?

```
    const params = {
      DesiredDeliveryMediums: ['EMAIL'],
      UserAttributes: [
        {
          Name: 'email',
          Value: email
        },
        {
          Name: 'email_verified',
          Value: 'True'
        },
      ],
      Username: email,
      UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    }

    cognitoIdentityService.adminCreateUser(params, function(err, data) {
      // ...
```

Comment: I think you’d have to configure settings somehow not to send out email invite, and then build your own system workflow by hand that would somehow verify email, which would then trigger the invitation email.... That said, without understanding your requirements, I would avoid this and redesign other parts of your system to align with Cognito workflow.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. If you set email_verified to true, then the email to verify the email is skipped, and the email appears as verified. The next flow would be NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED. By default, the user invitation message is sent. If it is not sent, check your SES config from user's pool settings.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I see my question was a bit unclear. I am quite happy for now.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent backend to send verification email, set MessageACtion="SUPPRESS"

```
    response = client.admin_create_user(
        UserPoolId='USER_POOL_ID',
        Username='USERNAME',
        TemporaryPassword='PASSWORD',
        UserAttributes=[
            {
                'Name': 'email',
                'Value': 'email@example.com'
            },
            {
                'Name': 'email_verified',
                'Value': 'true'
            }
        ],
        MessageAction='SUPPRESS'
    )
```